# How to pass persistence props to a React Navigation navigator in conjunction with createAppContainer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

The docs have this [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/state-persistence.html):

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({...});
const persistenceKey = "persistenceKey"
const persistNavigationState = async (navState) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(persistenceKey, JSON.stringify(navState))
  } catch(err) {
    // handle the error according to your needs
  }
}
const loadNavigationState = async () => {
  const jsonString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(persistenceKey)
  return JSON.parse(jsonString)
}

const App = () => <AppNavigator persistNavigationState={persistNavigationState} loadNavigationState={loadNavigationState} />;
```

**Now this is perfectly clear. What's not at all clear is how this can be used in conjunction with `createAppContainer` [which requires that you pass an object](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html):**

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(...);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

---

So if I have to pass `persistNavigationState` and `loadNavigationState` to `<AppNavigator />`, but I cannot pass `<AppNavigator />` to `createAppContainer`, I don't see how actually implementing this is possible. What am I overlooking?

Comment: I think you can just pass the App variable of the first example to your createAppContainer function and that should work.

Comment: Seems sensible enough, but if I pass `App` to `createAppContainer` I get: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Component.router.getStateForAction')`

Comment: @Slbox How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Nope. I managed to reconfigure my application to not need the props. I forget what my exact issue was, so I'm not sure exactly how I fixed it, but there's no easy workaround I'm aware of.